# Custom query in google spreadsheet using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to get values from selected columns of a spreadsheet.

Of course, the spreadsheet query function can cover that well. But query an external sheet keeps showing the Import Range (REF#) Internal Error (my guess is due to heavy traffic from the source sheet), and my target sheet have to be in working order all the time, since it is kind of like a hub for the candidates we recruit.

So my solution using script is getting the values of each column, and write those values into each columns of the target sheet. Essentially, I have to run a lot of similar loops in my script.

I'm wondering if there is a more productive and dynamic way to get the desired columns from another spreadsheet (kinda like query in scripted form)?

Comment: What do you mean by "dreaded importrange error"? Have you authorized importrange to connect to the external spreadsheet?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. The importrange (#REF!) Import Range Internal Error is what I'm referring to (I allowed the sheet to access all the source sheets). Some workarounds I tried did not fix the issue.
Further more, I want my sheet to only get and update the data every a set amount of time to reduce lag and memory consumption. That's why I used script. While my custom import range script works well, it can only get selected rows. Getting selected columns is a bit more complicated with my experience with scripting so far.